# How to change the default port of Graphite web-app?

Tags: nagios, graphite

I tried searching in the /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/local_settings.py file. But I did not find how to change the default port 80.
Actually, I wanted to install OMD on the same machine which by default installs on 80 port.

[Link for graphite doc](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-local-settings.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The recommended way to serve webapp is to use as WSGI backend

From http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#dependencies

> A WSGI server and web server. Popular choices are:
>
> - Apache with mod_wsgi
> - gunicorn with nginx
> - uWSGI with nginx

So to change port configure accordingly a vhost in the server (nginx or apache or other) of you choice to listen on the desired port.

If you want to serve via Django's runserver simply specify the port

```
/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<your_port>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using docker image for this purpose, you can download here: https://hub.docker.com/r/graphiteapp/docker-graphite-statsd

1. Getting the Docker image:

   `docker pull graphiteapp/docker-graphite-statsd`
2. start the docker, you can change the port easily:

   `docker run -d --name graphite --restart=always -p 80:80 -p 2003-2004:2003-2004 -p 2023-2024:2023-2024 -p 8125:8125/udp -p 8126:8126 graphiteapp/docker-graphite-statsd`

Answer (score 0):

vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf      and then add below line and save

Listen 192.168.1.1:4000

vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/apache2-graphite.conf

and change the port 80 into desire port

systemctl reload apache2

Comment: This is for Ubuntu 20